# How to make all C# classes in an assembly serializable

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, serializable, serializableattribute

Is there an easy way to make all classes in an assembly serializable instead of putting `[Serializable]` manually on top of each class?

I can't use reflection as attributes are static metadata and cannot be added dynamically, and I'm out of ideas how to achieve this.

**Why**

I'm writing a [security library](https://github.com/undergroundwires/SafeOrbit) that repeatedly checks state of its classes and throws `MemoryInjectionException` if a class has been modified by any external modifications. In order to achieve this I serialize all classes and save the hash of their serialization in a dictionary.

**Edit**: Ended up using a [self-modified version of SharpSerializer](https://github.com/undergroundwires/SafeOrbit/tree/master/src/SafeOrbit/Memory/InjectionDetection/InjectionDetector/Stampers/State/Serialization)

Comment: Sounds like something [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) might be able to do

Comment: You can use a serializer which doesn't care about the `Serializable` attribute (like `XmlSerializer`, for example)

Comment: I wonder if your application detects that the code that detects modifications has been modified.

Comment: As a plan B (or C or D) you could write a unit test to ensure that all the classes are serializable. It won't add the attribute but you'll know if someone leaves it off.

Comment: @stuartd PostSharp is too expensive. I wonder if I can achieve this easily with Fody. I have no idea how to code for Fody.

Comment: @GSerg Well I use strong-named assembly in order to avoid this.

Comment: @Jcl Thanks for the advice. Binary serialization is much faster (almost double). Fastest is the best as I use this check in my factory class (every time a new class is requested).

Comment: @U.Bulle you may want to try `http://www.sharpserializer.com/` which has comparable speeds to `BinaryFormatter` and doesn't require `[Serializable]`. It's not -as fast-, but it's pretty much ok. Other than that, Fody might do, but if you are not familiarized with it (or with compilation processes and IL opcodes), programming a fody add-in has a decently steep learning curve

Comment: What's wrong with having to write `[Serializable]` once in each class? Are there really that many to make this option so onerous? It would be rather simple to have a unit test to make sure all classes defined in the assembly are serializable so that can't be an issue either.

Comment: If you don't want to pay for postsharp, use mono.cecil

Comment: Find and replace `public class` with `[Serializable] public class`. Then look for build errors where `[Serializable]` is added twice and delete one.

Comment: @Jcl Thanks for this awesome library! It's much better than .NET's serialization. I've moved to it and my problem is solved.

Comment: @ScottHannen that's pretty genius :)